# Double sum over primes

Tags: summation, prime-numbers

Can anyone tell me the value of the sum 
$$\sum_{p\in \mathcal{P}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log (p^n)}{2}\left[\,p^{-n}-\psi\left(\frac{p^n+2}{2}\right)+\psi\left(\frac{p^n+1}{2}\right)\right].$$
$\psi(z)$ is the [digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html). The sum is over primes using *Mathematica*.

Comment: It is a related question I could not find the value of this sum

Comment: Read the answers to the linked question to get an idea how you could approximate the value.

Comment: Would you please post the code you used to try to find the sum?